# Invalid argument foreach() retornar mensagem em branco

Tags: php, mysql

```
<table border="1">
    <?php
        foreach($arrayReturn['qsa'] as $value){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>NOME:</td>
            <td><?=$value['qual'];?></td>
            <td><?=$value['nome'];?></td>
        </tr>


    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Acontece que as vezes não existe os valores no banco de dados. E eu recebo o seguinte erro: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/usuario/public_html/script.php

Como eu altero o código para escrever: "Não disponível"? Alguém consegue auxiliar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode verificar o array antes de ir para o foreach

```
if( is_array($arrayReturn['qsa']) && count($arrayReturn['qsa']) > 0 ) {
    // Aqui continua o seu foreach
}else{
    echo '<tr><td colspan="3">Não Disponível</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Ótimo Anderson! Perfeito!

Answer (score 2):

Basta verificares se índice existe desta forma

```
<?php if(isset($arrayReturn['qsa'])): ?>
     <?php foreach($arrayReturn['qsa'] as $value): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>NOME:</td>
                <td><?=$value['qual'];?></td>
                <td><?=$value['nome'];?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php else: ?>

<p>Não disponivel</p>

<?php endif;?>
```